# Find: $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{f(3+h^2)-f(3-h^2)}{2h^2} \right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $f^{'}(3) = 2$ then find

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{f(3+h^2)-f(3-h^2)}{2h^2} \right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

$$f(3 \pm h^2) = f(3) \pm h^2 f'(3) + O(h^3)$$

Then

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(3+h^2)-f(3-h^2)}{2h^2} = f'(3)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $3+h^2=k$, $(k-2h^2)=3-h^2$, Now that's a differential question.

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{f(k)-f(k-2h^2)}{2h^2} \right)=f'(3)$$

Answer (score 0):

When $x=2$ let $f=(3-h)^2=-2h$, use this to simplify the original equastion